# Get first two digits of a string, support for negative 'numbers'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following strings in JavaScript as examples:

```
-77.230202
39.90234
-1.2352
```

I want to ge the first two digits, before the decimal.  While maintaining the negative value.  So the first one would be '-77' and the last would be '-1'

Any help would be awesome!

Thank you.

Comment: Not very well defined: What does `-777` do? return `-770` because there is only a 2 digit accuracy, or `-777`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
var num = parseInt('-77.230202', 10);
alert(num);
```

See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/ss3d3/1/

**Note:** `parseInt()` can return `NaN`, so you may want to add code to check the return value.

Comment: Do you need `parseFloat()`? Seems like you could just use `.parseInt()`.

Comment: make sure you pass the radix.

Comment: The `parse*` methods accept strings and return numbers, in which case `parseInt` here receives a number, which isn't right. You just need `parseInt` anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but you could always use the double bitwise NOT `~~` trick:

```
~~'-77.230202'  // -77
~~'77.230202'   // 77

~~'-77.990202'  // -77
~~'77.930202'   // 77
```

No *octal* concerts with this method either.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = -77.230202;
var integer = num < 0 ? Math.ceil(num) : Math.floor(num);
```

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math.

Comment: Why've you got two arguments?

Comment: The OP said the value is a string. `round()` requires a number.

Comment: If the number is `-77.730202`, you'll get `-78` instead of `-77`.

Comment: @patrick: See edit. @Jason: JavaScript will coerce the string to a number. Try `Math.ceil("-77.6")`.

Comment: @davin: You are right, the second argument was bogus. Round was not right anyway, so I removed the suggestion altogether.

Comment: @Tomalak: To give a reference for the number coercion you mentioned: http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.2 *"Each of the following Math object functions applies the ToNumber abstract operator to each of its arguments (in left-to-right order if there is more than one) and then performs a computation on the resulting Number value(s)."* I just *had* to look it up. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: Nice, thank you. :) So strictly speaking it is an explicit cast there, but the result is the same. In any case, `parseInt()`  seems like the better alternative here.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, main point is that the spec covers the case for passing strings as you noted in your comment. And yes, `parseInt()` is probably clearest, but I like my `~~` even though its meaning isn't obvious. :o)

Answer (score 0):

try this, but you'd have to convert your number to a string.:

var reg = /^-?\d{2}/,
num = -77.49494;

console.log(num.toString().match(reg))

["-77"]

Comment: This would be a horrible use of regular expressions.

Comment: ya probably since you have to do the conversion.  i also just reread what was originally posted this wouldn't work actually b/c dave is looking for the first two digits before the decimal so if the number was > 100 it would fail...plus i just think a lot in regexp heh

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to return everything to the left of the decimal point?  If so, and if these are strings as you say, you can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var mystring = -77.230202;
var nodecimals = mystring.split(".", 1);
```